# Sharing WireGuard on macOS Mojave over WiFi

Tags: macos, wireless-router, hotspot, macos-mojave, wireguard

How would one create a hotspot on macOS Mojave and route all traffic from and to wireless interface through WireGuard interface?

I have a working WireGuard installation and I can access internet via `wg0` fine. I've tried Wireguard GUI, which creates a VPN profile I can use to share internet for clients connecting over WiFi. However, when activating internet sharing from OS settings, hotspot never activates (no SSID).

I've tried enabling packet forwarding and playing with `/etc/pf.conf` as described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/931827/sharing-openvpn-on-mac-os-x-yosemite), but I cannot get it working.